# Identifying subclass from superclass iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop, inheritance

I have a `BaseViewController` from which my `SearchViewController` is subclassed. I need to assign the target of a button in superclass to a method in subclass. I have a method in superclass called `addBackButton(_:)` which adds a button to the navigationView(custom made view). I call this method from the subclass .

## What I did(code is in swif 3):

The above method accepts a viewcontroller object and I call it from the subclass by passing `self` to the method.This way it is working fine. The method definition is like this:

```
 func addBackButton(from vc: AnyObject) {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 44, height: 44)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "back")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState())
        button.tintColor = currentTheme.navButtonTintColor
        if vc.isKind(of:SearchViewController.self) {
            let controller: SearchViewController = self as! SearchViewController
            button.addTarget(controller, action: #selector(controller.backButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        }
        navigationBarView.addSubview(button)
    }
```

**I have two questions:**

1. What is the right way of communication between superclass to subclass?
2. The above method is working fine. But if I do `'vc is SearchViewController'` and `'vc.isKind(of:SearchViewController.self)'`, both will work fine. Which is the right way to identify the subclass from superclass?

## Edit:

As per anbu.karthiks comment, I used the self inside the superclass to identify the subclass .

```
 func addBackButton() {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 44, height: 44)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "back")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState())
        button.tintColor = currentTheme.navButtonTintColor
        switch self {
        case is SearchViewController:
            let controller: SearchViewController = self as! SearchViewController
            button.addTarget(controller, action: #selector(controller.backButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            break
        case is HelpViewController:
            let controller: HelpViewController = self as! HelpViewController
            button.addTarget(controller, action: #selector(controller.backButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        navigationBarView.addSubview(button)
    }
```

Comment: yes correct ..., simple self is fine to identify the subclass

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.Karthik . I was thinking in a complex way.  I removed the function parameter and simply used a switch using `self` inside the superclass and is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the way you have done it works fine and is one way to do it. Another way to do this is the following:

```
if let controller = vc as? SearchViewController {
    // use controller in here which is casted to your class and ready to be used
}
```

So your code:

```
func addBackButton(from vc: AnyObject) {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 44, height: 44)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "back")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState())
    button.tintColor = currentTheme.navButtonTintColor
    if let controller = vc as? SearchViewController {
        button.addTarget(controller, action: #selector(controller.backButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    navigationBarView.addSubview(button)
}
```

> What is the right way of communication between superclass to subclass?

Nothing is right or wrong, but some methods are better than others. Check my example above for one example of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Rashwan .  Can you comment on using an `is` keyword to identify the superclass as I did? I have edited the question. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right approach to communicate between subClasses and superClass,
in fact, that approach is anti object oriented.

Doing downcasting in the `addBackButton()` function that located in the superclasses conflitcts with the idea of the object oriented.

in the super class you should put the generic code that comform with all the subclasses, if you need to add some extra code to the specific class, you should override the function and wirte the specif code to the specific subClass and call the super."functionName" if needed.

in your code you can create a function in the superClass called backButtonTapped()
and override this function in any subclass and wirte the specific code you need.

like this example:

```
class SuperClass: UIViewController {

    let navigationBarView = UINavigationBar()

    func addBackButton(from vc: AnyObject) {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 44, height: 44)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "back")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState())
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        navigationBarView.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func backButtonTapped() {
        //every subClass will override this funcion and handle it
    }
}

class Subclass: SuperClass {

    override func backButtonTapped() {
        //Do your specific code....
    }
}
```

I hope it was helpfull.